# Set Excel PageSetup.CenterHeader with variable/counter

Tags: excel, vba, printing

In my xlsx file I've one page with this fields Date, Time, Carrier, Destination, ordered by date/time
Each time that che date change I insert HPageBreaks

How I can print the center title with the correct data ?
I tried 1K way without rigth, the last are to set one variable with the first day into my Printarea.range minus one day, then the title will be the variable data plus the page number, obviously it doesn't work.
are possible to do what I thought''
any suggestion??

```
Titledata = 1th date to print - 1
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
TitleData = TitleData + 1
    .CenterHeader = "&C Elenco servizi del " & Format(TitleData + "&P", "dd-mmm")
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PrintArea = rgn.Address
    .PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Address
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = False
End With
```

Comment: Why is the string "&P" within the Format function?  Is the TitleData supposed to be a date?

Comment: @mooseman yes sure it's a date and I hope to add the &P, suppose that the TitleData are 01/01/2019 into 1th page TitleData +&P will be 02/01/2019, the tird page will be 04/01/2019, off course this is not the correct way (if it's really possible to do) I just ask you how I've to do

Comment: Then I believe the &P  will go at the end of that line.  Format(TitleData , "dd-mmm") + "&P"

Comment: @mooseman no, I tried
.CenterHeader = "&C Elenco servizi del " & Format(TitleData, "dd-mmm") + "&P"
and the result was 02-oct1, 02-oct3, 02-oct4, 02-oct5,....
so I tried
 CenterHeader = "&C Elenco servizi del " & DateAdd("d", "&P", Format(TitleData, "dd-mmm"))
but run-time '13' error show.
I think that the P value will be valorized just when the page were printed, and not one minute before  to use it as integer.

Comment: Is P a variable with a value?  putting it in quotes makes it look like you want the results to be 02-oct&P.  The plus sign and the ampersand are both used for concatenation.

Comment: @mooseman  &P are the VBA code in ActiveSheet.PageSetup that return "Prints the page number.", my goal will be to convert &P as integer to add at my date. Then, for each page printed, the Header will be different, each page the following day

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to show you how to increment the date by 1 day.   If you need to increment the month, just change the "d", to "m" in the Dateadd function

This will do it for each sheet in the workbook the x is increased for each new sheet.
You could do this with sh.index in stead of the x variable.

I hope this helps some to show you what is possible.

```
Sub Day_increase_header()
x = 0
For Each sh In Sheets

With sh.PageSetup
TitleData = Date
    .CenterHeader = "&C Elenco servizi del " & Format(DateAdd("d", x, TitleData), "dd-mmm")
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    '.PrintArea = rgn.Address
    .PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Address
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = False
End With
x = x + 1
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: as I wrote in the header of this tread, I've ONE sheet. in this sheet I've many records then when I print this sheet, the printer outpout are 4-5-xx pages.
Right, I want to customize the Header of each page printed.
The standard parameters to retreive the "corrente" page printed are &P, I ask you if exist some way to use the &P counter as parameter to add it at my variable.
I think that aren't possible.
Then I added one loop in my page that, for each break page insert one row and I put into my variable, then when I print this are the 1th row in each page.